# Is there a way to take regular backup of IBM watson conversation worksapce

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I have multiple workspaces on IBM Watson Assistant (Conversation) on IBM Cloud. As, we are training the system. I want a script that can take regular backups of the workspace to restore it any time we need.

Comment: My suggestion is to use Java SDK ( or any other language of your choice) and flush out workspaces(intents,entities,dialog) into file

Comment: @RiyaMRoy i looked into Node SDK but didn't got which API to use to get a dump of a workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Watson Conversation service has an API](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#apiexplorer) to export workspaces ([related blog](http://blog.4loeser.net/2017/03/manage-your-watson-conversations-from.html)). An example of that API is in my [Watson Conversation Tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/). You could use `cron` to kick off regular backups. [Bluemix OpenWhisk](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/openwhisk/index.html#getting-started-with-openwhisk) allows to trigger events using cron. Within the execution, export the workspace and write it out with a timestamp attached to Object Storage (on Bluemix or somewhere else).

BTW: With the Conversation API you can also fetch the timestamp of when the workspace was updated the last time, so that you only write out backups if it has been changed.